# gcloud run deploy works locally but not in the bitbucket pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I have two different outcomes when deploying a webapp to Cloud Run. Locally it works as expected. When running the build in a Bitbucket Pipeline via the .yaml build file it fails. Although the command is the same.

This is what my local try says:

```
gcloud run deploy importer-controlroom-frontend-dev --image=eu.gcr.io/myApp-cluster/importer-controlroom-frontend@sha256:976b7940b3ff62b495a946a0063de0d15d9dd1be2dbb4deab33eed94ff54d7a7 --cpu=100m --memory=64Mi --platform=gke --port=80 --timeout=10 --concurrency=1 --cluster=myApp-cluster-dev --cluster-location=europe-west3-a --connectivity=internal --namespace=dev

Deploying container to Cloud Run for Anthos service [importer-controlroom-frontend-dev] in namespace [dev] of cluster [myApp-cluster-dev]
Deploying new service...
Creating Revision...
```

In Bitbucket it looks like this:

```
+ gcloud run deploy importer-controlroom-frontend-$DEPLOYMENT_ENV --image=eu.gcr.io/myApp-cluster/importer-controlroom-frontend:$BITBUCKET_COMMIT --cpu=100m --memory=64Mi --platform=gke --port=80 --timeout=10 --concurrency=1 --cluster=$GCLOUD_CLUSTER --cluster-location=$GCLOUD_ZONE --connectivity=internal --namespace=$DEPLOYMENT_ENV
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) unrecognized arguments: europe-west3-a 
To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS
```

The used versions

```
Google Cloud SDK 300.0.0 (Bitbucket - there was no higher image tag on Dockerhub)
Google Cloud SDK 301.0.0 (Lokal)
```

I am kind of lost because the error message `unrecognized arguments: europe-west3-a`  is not very helpful and does not make sense imho.

Comment: Can you try to remove the equal sign `=` in the cluster region param `--cluster-location $GCLOUD_ZONE`? Let me know if it's better

Comment: Can you try printing the entire command that would be run, to ensure that your environment variables are correctly set? E.g. `echo gcloud run deploy importer-controlroom-frontend-$DEPLOYMENT_ENV ...`

Comment: From your output that starts with `+`, it's clear `--cluster-location=europe-west3-a` isn't making it to the command executed on bitbucket. So instead, it's recognized as a positional argument. My guess is because one of the bash variables is not defined.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere it works without the `=` thanks! Any explaination for that? Please add as answer

Comment: A stupid, and usual, bash bug! When you lose 3 days on that, you will remember it all your life !! :) :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is the following `ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) unrecognized arguments: europe-west3-a`

`europe-west3-a`, an argument??? Strange... But, I made an assumption: when you call your script, you pass this argument `--cluster-location=$GCLOUD_ZONE`. If `$GCLOUD_ZONE` contains a space at the beginning, the string replacement is the following

```
--cluster-location= europe-west3-a
```

Which means: "--cluster-location equal empty string (nothing immediately after the equal)" and an argument alone "europe-west3-a". The reason of your error.

If you remove the `=` sign, gcloud sdk takes the next printable string, remove all the space before and after and use it as parameter value.

You can also fix the issue by checking the `$GCLOUD_ZONE` value and by removing all the space before the region value. And thus keep the equal sign.